# Jquery on focus function

Tags: jquery

When `input` is focused I want its `color` and `border-bottom` to become blue but my script doesn't seem to work

```js
function dedaberi() {
  $('#addplanpopup .paperName').css({
    'borderBottom': '2px solid rgb(41, 134, 255)'
  });
  $('.floating-label').css({
    'color': 'rgba(41, 134, 255, 0.750)'
  });
}

if ($('#addplanpopup input').focusin()) {
  dedaberi();
} else {
  $('#addplanpopup .paperName').css({
    'borderBottom': '2px solid black'
  });
  $('.floating-label').css({
    'color': 'black'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addplanpopup">
  <input type="text" class="paperName" required/>
  <span class="floating-label">Your plan's head !</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focus`and `blur`. I think the way you try is not possible. `if($('#addplanpopup input').focusin())` is not how an event works. An event has to be registered, then it listens to what ever it has to.

```js
function dedaberi() {
  $('#addplanpopup .paperName').css({
    'borderBottom': '2px solid rgb(41, 134, 255)'
  });
  $('.floating-label').css({
    'color': 'rgba(41, 134, 255, 0.750)'
  });
}

$('#addplanpopup input').focus(function() {
  dedaberi();
})

$('#addplanpopup input').blur(function() {
  $('#addplanpopup .paperName').css({
    'borderBottom': '2px solid black'
  });
  $('.floating-label').css({
    'color': 'black'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addplanpopup">
  <input type="text" class="paperName" required/>
  <span class="floating-label">Your plan's head !</span>
</div>
```